# Increase point drawing precision

Tags: python, matplotlib

When drawing points with very close values, sometimes points with different values seem to have the same value.  On picture below, all six points have different ordinate values, yet it seems as if points 2,3 and points 4,5,6 have the same value.

I am aware that this is the problem of resolution (which I cannot increase for reasons not elaborated here).  Still, is there any possibility to tell `matplotlib` to draw these points more precisely?

[image]

MWE:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

coor = [[0.5,0.525,0.55,0.575,0.6,0.625],[0.5,0.501,0.502,0.503,0.504,0.505]]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3.5,3.5))
plts=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.01, right=0.99, bottom=0.01, top=0.99, hspace=0, wspace=0)

plts.set_xlim([0,1])
plts.set_ylim([0,1])
plts.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
plts.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

grph = plts.scatter(coor[0],coor[1],facecolor='k',marker='o',lw=0,s=25)
fig.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=100)
```

Comment: Change the axis limits?

Comment: @DavidG There are other points that fill the rest of the plot, so I cannot change limits (yet here I presented only problematic ones)

Comment: Setting `marker='+'` may look more precise, but there is not really much you can do to get around the resolution limit.

Comment: making the marker size smaller but if these are points on a much bigger plot then you will always have this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually the algorithm problem that appeared with `mathlab` version 1.4.  Read details here:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8533

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7233

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7262

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from the resoltion of 100 dpi. Since the dots'  positions need to be multiples of 1 pixel, their positions look discretized.

You can of course increase the dpi when saving the picture. The following is the original picture, saved with 100 dpi, showing the undesired behaviour.

[image]

The following is the picture saved with 300 dpi and afterwards downsampled to the same size as the original picture.

[image]

If you choose figure size such that 
`figsize*saved_dpi/desired_dpi == integer` the result would even better; but you would need to refrain from using `bbox_inches='tight'` then.

Comment: OK, I used PNG as an example, but what I actually do is making a video using ArtistAnimation.  Is it possible to make higher resolution and force ArtistAnimation to downsample while making video?

Comment: If I understand you right, pixel position discreditation of `matplotlib` is something we cannot go against.  Maybe removing pixel position discreditation would be a nice `matplotlib` enhancement request?

Comment: The downsampling would need to be done by the FileWriter you use for saving the animation, either by subclassing it and using PIL or by setting a respective argument to the external writer. Depending on which format you save in, this might actually be easy or hard. If you have a feature request for matplotlib, you can ask at the [GitHub site](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).

Comment: I am already the third person that reported that bug to GitHub.  See my own answer to my question.  Thanks for help.